# how to let the systemd cryptsetup automatically mount the usb key which contain keyfile?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, cryptsetup, crypttab

In ubuntu 19.10 I followed the example [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html). 
The keyfile is at the root of usb key filesystem. usbkey has uuid `yyyy`.
the `/etc/crypttab` is like this:

```
encrypted UUID=xxxx /keyfile:UUID=yyyy luks,keyfile-timeout=60,x-systemd.device-timeout=2min
```

The automatically generated generator is `/run/systemd/generator/systemd-cryptsetup@encrypted.service`

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-cryptsetup-generator

[Unit]
Description=Cryptography Setup for %I
Documentation=man:crypttab(5) man:systemd-cryptsetup-generator(8) man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8)
SourcePath=/etc/crypttab
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=true
After=cryptsetup-pre.target
Before=cryptsetup.target
RequiresMountsFor=/keyfile:UUID=yyyy
BindsTo=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-xxxx.device
After=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-xxxx.device
Before=umount.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=0
KeyringMode=shared
OOMScoreAdjust=500
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach 'encrypted' '/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxx' '/keyfile:UUID=yyyy' 'luks,keyfile-timeout=60'
ExecStop=/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup detach 'encrypted'
```

however, I did not see any thing related to mount the usb key in the `journalctl`. I always directly launch the `system-cryptsetup` and fail to find the file.

```
systemd-cryptsetup[1132]: Encountered unknown /etc/crypttab option 'keyfile-timeout=60', ignoring.
systemd-cryptsetup[1132]: WARNING: Locking directory /run/cryptsetup is missing!
systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
systemd-cryptsetup[1132]: Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 512 bits for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxx
systemd-cryptsetup[1132]: Failed to open key file.
systemd-cryptsetup[1132]: Failed to activate with key file '/keyfile:UUID=yyyy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debian has different implementation of crypttab, it simply does not support the standard systemd crypttab format, thus we cannot use that example. One need to use debian format to do it.